# PHP Sessions array

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have a sessions on a page that stores an array

```
<?php session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['pages'])) {
$_SESSION['pages'] = array();
array_push($_SESSION['pages'],$description);
}
print_r($_SESSION['pages']);
?>
```

Is there a way to limit the array to only 3 descriptions before it rewrites over the first array. For example

```
array[0] => page1
array[1] => page2
array[2] => page3
```

no when I visit the 4 page I want it to rewrite over 1 and just keep the 3 records so then it would look like

```
array[0] => page4
array[1] => page2
array[2] => page3
```

I don't know if this is possible or not!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just an array, so it's very simple.

However, instead I would add an element at the start and remove one at the end if there are more than 3 elements:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['pages']))
{
  $_SESSION['pages'] = array();
}

// add an element at the start
array_unshift($_SESSION['pages'], $description);

// remove an element at the end
if (count($_SESSION['pages']) > 3)
{
  array_pop($_SESSION['pages']);
}

print_r($_SESSION['pages']);
```

That way your order is always the same (last, previous, 2 ago).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this would be possible if you create a new class.  That class can have a list and an index as it's members.

When you call my_class_push you can push the element into the current index and the increment it.  If the index==3 then set it to be 0 again.

Does that make sense?

Alternatively you can store the index in a session variable then write your own push function that will get the index variable of the session do the necessary assignment and change the session index variable.